# Non-blocking java cache that reloads asynchronously as long as some value is available

Tags: java, caching

I need a memoizer/cache-like structure that only blocks the first time *ever* a value is requested and only periodically refreshes (asynchronously, triggered by user request) afterwards. Where can I find one ?

Answer (score 1):

You can achive this in Ehcache with a [SelfPopulatingCache](http://ehcache.org/apidocs/net/sf/ehcache/constructs/blocking/SelfPopulatingCache.html).